# Coffeescript and Rendering SVG in an If condition

Tags: svg, coffeescript

I'm trying to create a battery checker for an application which interprets coffeescript. I'm new to coffeescript and googling didn't help.

Below is the code I tried:

```
if charge <= 100
  render: ->"""
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M0 0h24v24h-24z" fill="none"/>
      <path d="M7 17v3.67c0 .73.6 1.33 1.33 1.33h7.33c.74 0 1.34-.6 1.34-1.33v-3.67h-10z"/>
      <path fill-opacity=".3" d="M17 5.33c0-.73-.6-1.33-1.33-1.33h-1.67v-2h-4v2h-1.67c-.73 0-1.33.6-1.33 1.33v11.67h10v-11.67z"/>
    </svg>
  """
```

Charge is filled with the batterypercentage. If I try to render the svg outside of the if condition it works, but sadly not with the if.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `render` in your code ?

Comment: As far as I know render is used by Javascript to render HTML e.g. the SVG here in my code. Render works outside the If-Condition but not inside

Comment: It's not there as a global. Are you using any libraries?

Comment: Oh pardon, my bad, it's the application that interprets render. The application is [Übersicht](https://github.com/felixhageloh/uebersicht)

Comment: This is an Übersicht specific problem. Figure out what the object you're applying the properties to is called. then do something like `this.render = …`

Comment: Even if I render it with my `render: (output) ->""""` it does not work. It puts out its Status e.g. charged 100%, but does not render the SVG

Comment: I tried using a SwitchCase instead of If (which would be cleaner anyways), but it does not work either. I'm running out of ideas

Comment: The `if` ist checking on the Battery status once again, just so i can determine a SVG to be rendered, e.g. below 50% is a diffrent SVG than it is above 50%. It supposably runs a function, the `render` function returns a HTML string to render this widget. But it checks the `if` but does not run `render`. but works if its before the `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your code compile into in [coffescript.org](http://coffescript.org)'s console :

```
if (charge <= 100) {
  ({
    render: function() {
      return "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\" viewBox=\"0 0 24 24\">\n  <path d=\"M0 0h24v24h-24z\" fill=\"none\"/>\n  <path d=\"M7 17v3.67c0 .73.6 1.33 1.33 1.33h7.33c.74 0 1.34-.6 1.34-1.33v-3.67h-10z\"/>\n  <path fill-opacity=\".3\" d=\"M17 5.33c0-.73-.6-1.33-1.33-1.33h-1.67v-2h-4v2h-1.67c-.73 0-1.33.6-1.33 1.33v11.67h10v-11.67z\"/>\n</svg>";
    }
  });
}
```

Which does nothing.

You should consider removing the `:` after `render`.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but if the ´:´ is gone, it says No command given.